# TypeError at post/4/remove : 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I am trying to delete a post (confirm delete) using `DeleteView`. I ran into the below error:

> TypeError at /post/4/remove/
>   'str' object is not callable

New to Django-working on a blog application. Other functionalities are working fine but when I attempt to delete a post (confirm delete). I ran into the below error:

urls.py: http://codepad.org/SP55psyf

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name ='post_remove'),
    ...
]
```

views.py: http://codepad.org/BVsApXhB (complete file)

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')
```

Models.py : http://codepad.org/TLUo4NJG

post_confirm_delete.html : http://codepad.org/795iD3RB

Comment: You need to make a [mcve]. Links can and will die.

Comment: Include the full traceback in your question, it will show where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question posted, see ['str' object is not callable when i try to use DeleteView in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817018/3629379).
And [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) argument should has specific value, not simple strings.

```
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

You need to use `models.PROTECT` instead of `PROTECT` string.